# Interpreting the determinant of matrices of dot products

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, exterior-algebra

In the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ consider two (ordered) sets of vectors $a_1 \ldots a_k$ and $b_1 \ldots b_k$ with $k \le n$.

> **Question**
>
> 1. What is the geometrical interpretation of $\det(a_i \cdot b_j)?$
> 2. Is it true that $\det(a_i\cdot b_j)=\det(a'_p\cdot b'_q)$ if $a_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a_k=a'_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a'_k$ and $b_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b_k=b'_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b'_k?$

Since $\det(a_i\cdot a_j)$ equals the squared $k$-volume spanned by $a_1\ldots a_k$, I guess that $\det(a_i\cdot b_j)$ may be interpreted as the $k$-volume spanned by some kind of projection of $b_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b_k$ (thought of as an oriented $k$-parallelogram) onto $a_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a_k$. For the same reason I would answer affirmatively to the second question.

Comment: By $\det(a_i \cdot b_j)$, do you mean the determinant of the matrix $(a_i \cdot b_j)_{ij}$? Isn't this matrix the same as $AB$, where $A = (a_1, \dotsc, a_k)$ and $B = (b_1, \dotsc, b_k)^t$?

Comment: @AndréCaldas: Yes to both questions.

Comment: +1: A very interesting question on a rather neglected subject: euclidean structures on exterior products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Given a Euclidean  structure on $\mathbb R^n$, you deduce a canonical euclidean structure on each  $\Lambda ^k\mathbb R^n$.
   On pairs of decomposable elements    $a_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a_k, b_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b_k\in\Lambda ^k\mathbb R^n$  it is given by the formula
   $$      (a_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a_k\mid b_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b_k)= \det(a_i\cdot b_j)                                                     $$
   So your determinant is the scalar product of two vectors, but in a new vector space.
   In particular you have the pleasant interpretation that the volume of the parallelipiped spanned by the vectors $a_1, \ldots ,a_k\in V$ is the length of the vector $a_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a_k\in \Lambda ^k\mathbb R^n$.
2. The above interpretation makes it now obvious that given    $$\omega =a_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a_k,  \:\omega '=a'_1\wedge \ldots \wedge a'_k, \eta=b_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b_k, \eta'=b'_1\wedge \ldots \wedge b'_k$$ the equalities  $\omega=\omega'$ and $\eta=\eta'$ imply that   $$(\omega\mid\eta)=\det(a_i\cdot b_j)=(\omega'\mid\eta')=\det(a'_p\cdot b'_q)$$

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I'm linking this to another closely related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140180/a-scalar-product-in-the-space-of-oriented-volumes

Comment: This is another related answer, more algebraic in nature, that I found useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/44212/8157