# Generalizing the geometric interpretation of dot product to simple $k$-vectors

Tags: reference-request, inner-products, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, geometric-interpretation

**Background:** For $u, v \in \mathbb R^n$, the dot product $u \cdot v$ can be interpreted geometrically as follows:

1. Its magnitude is the product of the lengths of $u$ and $\operatorname{proj}_{u} v$.
2. Its sign is $+1$ if $u$ and $\operatorname{proj}_{u} v$ point in the same direction, and $-1$ if they point in opposite directions.

Similarly, here is a geometric interpretation for the dot product of two simple $k$-vectors. Recall that the (standard) dot product in $\Lambda^k(\mathbb R^n)$ is given by
$$(u_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge u_k) \cdot (v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k) = \det(u_i \cdot v_j)_{i,j=1}^k.$$

Let $P(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ be the (oriented) $k$-dimensional parallelogram generated by $u_1, \ldots, u_k$. Then it seems to me that $(u_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge u_k) \cdot (v_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge v_k)$ can be interpreted geometrically as follows:

1. Its magnitude is the product of the $k$-dimensional volumes of of $P(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ and $\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{span}(u_1, \ldots, u_k)} P(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$.
2. Its sign is $+1$ if $P(u_1, \ldots, u_k)$ and $\operatorname{proj}_{\operatorname{span}(u_1, \ldots, u_k)} P(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ have the same orientation, and $-1$ if they have opposite orientations.

(To prove this, first note that it is true when $u_1, \ldots, u_k$ are orthonormal. Then use Gram-Schmidt to reduce to the orthonormal case.)

**Question:** After searching on the internet and in various textbooks, I cannot find this geometric description anywhere. (I did see it briefly mentioned in the question in [Interpreting the determinant of matrices of dot products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152284/interpreting-the-determinant-of-matrices-of-dot-products), but it was not addressed in the answer.) That is surprising to me because it seems like a natural generalization of the $k=1$ geometric interpretation, which (I believe) is commonly taught. Is there a textbook or reference that contains the interpretation above for $k > 1$? (Or, did I make a mistake somewhere?)

Comment: I also came to the same conclusion as you, and similarly was not able to find the interpretation elsewhere. In other words, $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$ for unit $k$-forms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ describes the (signed) "scale factor" associated with orthogonal projecting from $\alpha$'s (oriented) $k$-subspace to $\beta$'s (oriented) $k$-subspace. This also means $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle=\|\alpha\|\|\beta\|\cos\theta$ where magnititude describes absolute volume of parallelotopes and the convex angle $\theta$ describes the dihedral between $\alpha$ and $\beta$'s associated $k$-subspaces.

Comment: Whether $\theta$ is acute or obtuse depends on if orthogonally projecting one subspace onto the other preserves or reverses orientation. We can generalize even further to a $k$-vector and an $\ell$-vector with $k\ne\ell$ too! The matrix $G=A^TB$ is no longer square, but $\det(G^TG)=(\|\alpha\|\|\beta\|\cos\theta)^2$. If we project a $k$-subspace onto an $\ell$-subspace with $k>\ell$, $G$ has linearly dependence, so $\det(G^TG)=0$, which makes sense as $\ell$-volume is zero $k$-volume. If $k<\ell$, we can't say how projection affects orientation, but $\cos^2$ is positive anyway so it whatever!

Comment: (The angle $\theta$ only makes sense if the subspaces intersect at a common hyperplane, but the "scale factor associated with orthogonal projection" is a universal interpretation.)

Comment: @runway44 Thanks for the comments! I guess this means my question is really a reference request as opposed to a "is this correct?" question, so I've edited the last few sentences accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this geometric description in Chapter 3 of David Bachman's *A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms* (2nd edition).