# Scalar product of two Slater determinants

Tags: real-analysis, quantum-mechanics

this is my first question on MSE so I hope to get it right. I'm trying to prove the following fact about Slater determinants:
\begin{equation}
\langle \psi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \psi_N, \phi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \phi_N \rangle = \det(\langle \psi_i, \phi_j \rangle),
\end{equation}
where my definition of Slater determinants is the usual one:
\begin{equation}
\psi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \psi_N := \frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}}\det(\psi_i(x_j)) = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{N!}}\sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma_N}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\psi_{\sigma(1)}(x_1)\dots\psi_{\sigma(N)}(x_N)
\end{equation}
Here is my attempt:\begin{align*}
        &\langle \psi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \psi_N, \phi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \phi_N \rangle = \frac{1}{N!}\sum_{\sigma, \tau \in \Sigma_N}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\text{sgn}(\tau)\langle \psi_{\sigma(1)},\phi_{\tau(1)}\rangle \dots \langle \psi_{\sigma(N)},\phi_{\tau(N)}\rangle =\\
        & = \sum_{\tau \in \Sigma_N}\text{sgn}(\tau)\Bigg(\frac{1}{N!}\sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma_N}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\langle \psi_{\sigma(1)},\phi_{\tau(1)}\rangle \dots \langle \psi_{\sigma(N)},\phi_{\tau(N)}\rangle \Bigg)
    \end{align*}
To get the determinant, the sum in parentheses should reduce to the product $\langle \psi_1,\phi_{\tau(1)}\rangle \dots \langle \psi_N,\phi_{\tau(N)}\rangle$, but I don't see why that should be true: any kind of hint is warmly welcome :)

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140180/8157) is exactly the same object, so that linked question may be useful to you. (Do they call these "Slater determinants"? Must be a quantum mechanical jargon. In pure maths these are plain dull "scalar products on exterior algebras" or something like that).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, in QM these are called Slater determinants for historical reasons, and indeed they form a basis of the exterior algebra of the 1-particle Hilbert space. However I don’t think I need to get so sophisticated to solve this problem :)

Comment: You cannot conceive the pleasure you gave me  writing the name of my old friend John

Comment: Another "coating" of your issue is by expressing in two different ways the determinant of the product of matrices $\Phi \Psi^T$, if you see what I mean by these notations.